# Is it possible to save and call data from an EXE file? Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, passwords

So I have to make a program for secret stuff, and have to save the password in a file. Can i stock it directly into an EXE file from a batch file like:

```
echo pass=1234>password.exe
```

like if it was a batch file?
Because i don't want people to open this file and see the password.

Please be helpful and tell me where my mistake is, Thank you

Comment: your code creates a textfile named `password.exe` with the content `pass=1234`. Although it's a good idea to change the extesion to something nobody would think of opening it with an editor, you should also use a more boring name than "password". You can also hide this file with `attrib +h file.ext`. Not that would help, if soneone knows how to use Windows and/or Cmd-line...

Comment: by the way: to read the string, use `set /p pass=<password.exe` (or better another name, like "Win64-tool.exe". One have to read (and understand) your script to get the idea to take a look into a file with such a name.

Comment: Thanks! The password.exe was just an example, but i didn't quite catch the hiding part

Answer (score 0):

this *only* works, if `password.exe` supports input via STDIN:

```
echo pass=1234|password.exe
```